# Ranking with errors

Tags: reference-request, randomness, sorting

I am looking for references for the following problem, which I feel must have been studied before. I have n items and I want to rank them.  I randomise once at the beginning of the
process and then for each pair of items I have an x% chance of getting the
right ordering, let us say independently. I then use these comparison results to rank the items.  I would like to know how good/bad the ranking can be given unbounded computation and also any methods for finding a good ranking in reasonable time.  Let us also say that there is a true total ordering under the hood.

I am aware of some of the literature on binary sorting with errors but the papers I found, at least, seem to answer a different set of questions.

Comment: For adversarial errors see http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/423/any-fast-algorithm-for-minimum-cost-feedback-arc-set-problem/ .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly it is answered in Braverman and Mossel's "Sorting with Noisy Information" http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/arxiv/pdf/0910/0910.1191v1.pdf (see also conference version titled "Noisy Sorting without Resampling" IIRC.)

Comment: This is an excellent reference, which answers the question as I interpreted it.  It also mentions the query complexity, which requires $O(n\log(n))$ (possibly erroneous) comparison queries.

Comment: Thanks very much Warren.  I think that is the perfect paper for me to be getting on with.

Comment: A longer term link: http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.1191